# How to ignore invalid SSL certificate errors in Guzzle 5

Tags: php, ssl, curl, guzzle

This should be an easy thing to do. I can find plenty of references to how to do it in Guzzle 3, but they don't work in Guzzle 5.

What I am doing so far:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => 'false'
]]);
```

When I send a request though I get this error:

```
RequestException in RequestException.php line 51:
SSL CA bundle not found: false
```

I cannot find any useful reference to this error on google. If I could get access to the curl options then I could try something like the solution suggested here (which is for Guzzle 3, hence why it doesn't work): http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony2-guzzle-ssl-self-signed-certificate/, the relevant section of which is:

```
$req->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$req->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: OK, apparently I'm just bad at reading the docs. Eventually found this: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=ssl#how-can-i-add-custom-curl-options

Answer (score 104):

You should use

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);
```

i.e. a Boolean false, not the string 'false'

The documentation is here:
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html#verify

Note: a few people have given other answers that apply to Guzzle 6+. They're good answers if you are using those versions (but the original question was explicitly about Guzzle 5).

Comment: The ```defaults``` is actually not a part of the Guzzle 5 Client's config. You should use:

    $this->client = new GuzzleClient([
      'verify' => false
    ]);

Comment: Docs page is slightly changed to: http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#verify

Comment: To clarify, this answer is specific to Guzzle 5 (the version mentioned in the question), which does have `defaults` (see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html).

Answer (score 64):

Try with updated version that works:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['base_uri' => 'https://api.example.com/', 'verify' => false ]);
```

or a more simple version:

```
    $this->client = new GuzzleClient(['verify' => false ]);
```

Tested with version 6.2-dev.

Answer (score 58):

The actual version is **the correct one**:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['verify' => false ]);
```

At 2018, this does not work:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);
```

Answer (score 12):

you can use in the new laravel  client version with

```
$http = new Client(['verify' => false]);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for newer versions of Guzzle.

Comment: it works on Guzzle 7

Answer (score 0):

For someone using Laravel [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/http-client) below solution worked for me

```
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

 Http::baseUrl('http://example.com')
        ->setClient(new Client(['verify' => false]))
        ->get('user/lits.htm',[
          'page_no' => '5',
          'per_page' => '25',
        ])
        ->json();
```