# curl 60 err Unable to get local issuer Ubuntu Nginx vmware

Tags: symfony, nginx, curl, openssl, guzzle

I am running a VM on Ubuntu 18.04 an using a self signed ssl certificate (openssl). I installed the CA AUthority, uploaded it to Chrome.  Chrome recognizes the SSL so I am not getting and error there, I do however get a guzzle error in Symfony.  I have tried editing php.ini and inputing the cacert.pem there and nothing is working. **this is not a duplicate please**

I am reaching out to see if anybody has run into this based on the stack above.

Comment: guzzle cant know about your installed ca in chrome. use the curl option to ignore ssl verification see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066409/how-to-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-in-guzzle-5

and yes - it is a duplicate :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore invalid SSL certificate errors in Guzzle 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066409/how-to-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-in-guzzle-5)